# The reputation graph doesn't match the current reputation of the user

Tags: support, reputation, migration

Looking at the graph reported for [kaybenleroll](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/277?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), I would take his reputation is close to 300, but that is not the reputation reported for him.

Why is there such difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because the question he got all his rep from was **migrated from Stack Overflow**.

So some of the votes happened here; others happened on SO proper.

I recalculated his rep and now it matches.